# Trigger DynamoDB Stream for Large Data Set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a lambda which gets triggered by DynamoDB Streams.
I would like to trigger that lambda for each item in the table (more than 100.000 items in one table - one item is around 500bytes).

How could I achieve that?

I have created a lambda which queries the DynamoDB table, gets each item and sends a message on the EventBridge containing the ID, so that another Lambda (Triggered by that ID) could update the item with a field 'createdAt' where I would just pass the EPOCH time.
After 300 items queried, I receive a timeout because memory of the lambda is exceed (256mb). This is unfortunately not a good solution.

My code looks something like this

```
updateByMId: async (mId, fn) => {
    const paginator = paginateQuery(paginatorConfig, {
        TableName: tableName,
        KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#pk': 'mId' },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall({ ':pk': mId }, { removeUndefinedValues: true }),
    })

    const promises: Promise<void>[] = []
    for await (const page of paginator) {
        const records = (page.Items || []).map(item => unmarshall(item) as Record)
        for (const record of records) {
            promises.push(fn(record))
        }
    }
    await Promise.all(promises)
},
```

the function which is being passed to this method is:

```
putEvent: async (message) => {
    const output = await client.send(new eventbridge.PutEventsCommand({
        Entries: [{
            EventBusName: eventBusName,
            Source: 'foo',
            DetailType: 'bar',
            Detail: JSON.stringify(message),
        }],
    }))

    if (output.FailedEntryCount !== undefined && output.FailedEntryCount > 0) {
        throw new Error(`Error putting event on bus! ${JSON.stringify(output.Entries)}`)
    }
    logger.info(`Successfully put event on bus`, { message })
},
```

Comment: Scanning 100k items should be done after a few seconds, maybe minutes, increases the timeout and the memory of the lambda and maybe show the code. How large are the items?

Comment: `I would like to trigger that lambda for each item in the table` - you mean for each change or for every item in the table? If you want to run something for every item in the table, streams are not the way to go.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary yea, i'm also not very happy with it but I can't think of any solution at the moment..

Comment: @luk2302 the items are around 500bytes each. so there is no way that the items will have more than 256mb.  I assume there might be some more data in the context of the lambdas or in the message that I'm sending which might cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that's reasonably tolerant of failures:

1. scan the table
2. write the item keys to an SQS queue
3. configure a Lambda function on that SQS queue to process the queue in batches of, say, 10 messages
4. have the Lambda function write a date attribute to the item associated with each key, as needed

Personally, I would not use a Lambda function to perform that initial scan.